# Change onclick attribute doesnt work

Tags: jquery, onclick, attr

I have one function and when i use it one or two times it works fine, but when i use it more times does not work fine, and the change of the `onclick` attribute does not works more times.

```
<div class="box_title" onclick="MostrarMyText(1, 1)" id="menu1">QUIÉNES SOMOS</div>
<div class="box_title" onclick="MostrarMyText(2, 2)" id="menu2">QUIÉNES SOMOS</div>
<div class="box_title" onclick="MostrarMyText(3, 3)" id="menu3">QUIÉNES SOMOS</div>
<div class="box_title" onclick="MostrarMyText(4, 4)" id="menu4">QUIÉNES SOMOS</div>

function MostrarMyText(id_txt, id_esconder){
    if (TouchedByUser == 94){       
        $('#menu'+id_txt).animate({

            width : '+=5%'
        }, 500);
        $('#MyText'+id_txt).show( 2500);
        TouchedByUser = 74;
    }
    else{
        $('#menu'+id_esconder).animate({

            width : '-=5%'
        }, 500);    
        $('#menu'+id_txt).animate({

            width : '+=5%'
        }, 3000);
        $('#MyText'+id_esconder).hide(2500);
        $('#MyText'+id_txt).show(5500);
    }
    // I believe the problem is with this loop
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        $('#menu'+ i).unbind('onclick');
        $('#menu'+ i).attr('onclick', 'MostrarMyText('+i+', '+id_esconder+')');
    }

}
```

I was searching and reading documentation for a several hours (I think the problem is inside `for`), but i cant solve this.

Comment: `FOR (i;` is a syntax error. Also note that `unbind` has nothing to do with attributes. It only removes event handlers bound via jQuery. However, you will get better help if you explain exactly what "doesn't work".

Comment: please be serius it was tried with for (i = 4; i <= 4; i++) {}, seryusli: ---> the change of the onclick atribute does not works more times.

Comment: I am serious. `FOR (i; i <= 4; i++)` is a syntax error, `for (i; i <= 4; i++)` is fine. JavaScript is case sensitive. Make sure you post the code you are actually using.

Comment: I use FOR to emphasize, original for  --->  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {} you need JPG to believe me, try this on your own pc, or where you whant

Comment: I'll leave it with the original to not confuse people

Comment: I don't need need any JPEG. I need you to post the actual code you are using, so that we can focus on the actual problem and are not distracted by errors you introduced posting here. If you want to emphasize something in your code, add a comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65550/discussion-between-arrain-gorria-and-felix-kling).